# is it possible to join two tables on basis of a column which is a foreign of third table in hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

For example I have two tables: `Stock_details` and `order_details`.

Both of these tables are not mapped directly but both of them have one column `product_id` in them which refers to the `Product` table.

So is there any way to join both of these tables using hibernate?

Comment: Join them to what? Product? Order? Can you tell us your use case? Do you want Order details to show the stock of a product?

Comment: Hibernate doesn't join tables. It joins entities associated with each other. Show us the entities, and tell us what your query should return.

Answer (score 1):

The Hibernate Criteria API is very limited. You can operate on the fields that are mapped in your entities.

HQL, however, gives you very much flexibility, compared to the SQL. You can write queries similar to those in the SQL. So, yes, you can join those tables using either joins or only WHERE conditions.

You can use in HQL queries entities that have no relations between them defined in the hibernate itself. They only need to be all mapped in Hibernate. You use entity names instead of column names and property names instead of column names.

Comment: thanks it helped me but I am having one query in this:after joining two tables using where query(theta join) I have to display columns from both the tables on a JSP but in this case I will be getting a list in which each row corresponds to array of objects so ata atime I can access columns from one table only.So is there any way to display data from columns from both the tables?